# JavaFX 8.0 -- TableView editing property is getting reset

Tags: javafx, clojure, javafx-8, clojure-java-interop

I'm doing a custom TableCell in JavaFX8, using Clojure on Win7 x64.

I'm defining a custom `TableCell` which can render different things, based on the type of item in the cell: when `TableCell.updateItem()` is called by the framework, it looks at the cell item and sets its graphics and text items accordingly.  As part of this, it looks at the `TableCell`'s `editingProperty` value returned by `TableCell.isEditing()`.

Somehow, this `editingProperty` is changing behind the scenes in certain conditions.

I can override the `TableCell.startEdit()` function and change the cell contents when the user clicks in the cell.  In this method, calling `TableCell.isEditing()` returns `True`, as one would expect.

However if I shrink the window down so there is *no* cell content visible (only the titlebar) and then open it back up again while the cell is editing, then the `updateItem()` method is called, as expected, but `TableCell.isEditing()` now returns `False`, and the cell renders the non-editing version again.

Whereas with a mouse defocus, or clicking on another cell will trigger a `TableCell.cancelEdit()`, there is no such thing triggered when this `editingProperty` is changed by shrinking the window and opening it back up again.

I put a `changeListener` on the `editingProperty` and can observe the property change into the editing state when I click on the cell, or into non-editing state when I click away from the cell or sort the table, but when I shrink the table and open it back up again, there is no changeListener event, and in the `updateItem()` the `editingProperty` value is False.

I thought maybe there is a new TableCell being created when the window shrinks and opens up again, so the `editingProperty` state is lost, but I checked that and it's the same address/pointer/whatever each time.

So the question then is how to maintain the `isEditing` state through a window shrink, or through a sort event, etc?  At least with the sort event the `changeListener` sees the `editingProperty` change.  But with a window shrink and reopen, I get no such event.  Sounds like a bug.

Thanks

Comment: hmm .. bugs are highly probable when it comes to tableView editing but can't reproduce with plain javafx

Comment: have to paddle back (before didn't follow your instructions exactly;-): I _can_ reproduce - with a plain TextFieldTableCell - the editing stop without notification if the table content (== all rows, to last millimeter) are no longer visible when shrinking the window size

Comment: Yup, the window has to shrink so only the title bar is visible, down to the last pixel.  Not a big deal.  There is almost no use case where I want to maintain the editing state during this transition.  It does appear to get defocused however, and I have a handler which commits the cell content upon a defocus event.